# Can the appID in appgallery change?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, pushkit, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

I use the push kit to send notifications to Huawei devices. As you know, when using API, it is necessary to give an appId in the link as follows. "https://push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v1/**app_id**/messages:send"

I will define a firewall rule for this link. **So I was wondering if the appId might change**. Because if appId changes I will have to change the definition as well.

Could you please give me information on this subject if I ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `app_id` in the link is the identifier of the app receiving your push messages.

Once an app is registered with AppGallery and gets allocated an `app_id`, then this identifier cannot be changed anymore. During the whole life of the app inside AppGallery, `app_id` stays the same.

In conclusion, if you target just one app, `app_id` will not change in the link. But maybe at some point you wish to send push messages to a new app you develop, with its own `app_id` different than the original one - case in which the difference will be reflected in the link.